# Material date picker with firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular-material2, angularfire2, angular6

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings), firestore from angularfire2 defaults all Date objects to Timestamp objects, So this is breaking the two-way data binding in Material Date Picker. Is there an alternative to achieve the same?

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: @TimM fixed the link.

Comment: I was able to come up with a work around after a long break, I just converted the Timestamp objects to Date objects using the map operator from rxjs and everything else goes back to how it was working before the ng6 update.